# SQL latest entries of table1 based for each group [base1.col1, base2.col2]

Tags: sql

We have 2 tables:

```
sale_stores [store_id, created_at, ...]
albums [id, sale_stores_id, album_code, created_at, ...]
```

And a 1-1 relationship between those two tables, with join on `sale_stores_id`

---

**GOAL**

We are trying to get the latest sale_stores object for each couple `[sale_stores.store_id, albums.album_code]`.

`created_at` timestamp can be used to get latest object but `id` is prefered.

Moreover, we need to access the `album_code` from the resulting objects

---

**EXAMPLE**

The query on the following data should return `sale_stores` objects:

- id 3 (latest for store 92 and album_code 123123)
- id 3 (latest for store 91 ahd album_code 123123)
- id 4 (latest for store 92 and album_code 234234)

  sale_stores

  | id | store_id |
  | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 91 |
  | 2 | 92 |
  | 3 | 91 |
  | 4 | 92 |

  albums

  | id | sale_store_id | album_code | created_at |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 1 | 123123 | jan 21 |
  | 2 | 2 | 123123 | feb 21 |
  | 3 | 3 | 123123 | mar 21 |
  | 4 | 4 | 234234 | sep 21 |

We tried max + group by but without success

```
SELECT sale_stores.*, albums.*, MAX(albums.id) max_id
FROM sale_stores
INNER JOIN albums
ON albums.sale_store_id = sale_stores.id
GROUP BY sale_stores.store_id, albums.album_code
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to select one row per group:

```
SELECT ssa.*
FROM (SELECT ss.*, a.*,  -- you may not want all these columns
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ss.id, a.album_code ORDER BY a.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sale_stores ss JOIN
           albums a
           ON a.releases_store_id = s.id
     ) ssa
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to replace a few things but ROW_NUMBER+PARTITION was it.
`
SELECT ssa.*
FROM (SELECT ss.*, a.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ss.store_id, a.album_code ORDER BY a.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sale_stores ss JOIN
           albums a
           ON a.releases_store_id = ss.id
     ) ssa
WHERE seqnum = 1;
`